# Displaying FILTER Value In Single Cell Based On Existing Cell Value

Tags: google-sheets

I have been working on a solution for a specific sheet I have to display data in a specific way, but have been struggling without gain for the past day.

I basically want to check through several columns and find the first non-blank value in that range on condition that a specific cell has a certain value.

Let me go more in-depth:

I have a sheet that pulls information from a form, and an example cell has a single formula for that entire column, as it uses the FILTER formula.

```
=FILTER('Form Responses'!$D:D, 'Form Responses'!$B:B = "Outgoing" )
```

The D column in the Form Responses sheet contains numerical values.

The B column in the Form Responses sheet contains either the text "Incoming" or "Outgoing".

For this specific column, I find references of "Outgoing" and if it is found then we list the value of the parallel D column. So if we had "Outgoing" in B3 then we would get the value of whatever is in D3. B17 and D17, B143 and D143, etc.

All of this works well, but the issue I am having specifically is when it comes to finding the value that can be anywhere among multiple columns (G:T).

From column G to column T I have sub-categories that are selected at the form level and put into the form response sheet.

What I need to do is find the "Outgoing" or "Incoming" value's specific sub-category, and that is where I am struggling.

I managed to put together several formulas that ALMOST achieve what I need:

```
 =FILTER('Form Responses'!$G:T, 'Form Responses'!$B:B = "Outgoing" )
```

HOWEVER, it displays the contents in different cells, as per the original sub-categories.

What do I mean by this?

If I have sub-categories that can be in columns from G to T in the Form Responses sheet then I want to find that specific value (there can only ever be ONE sub-category per row) and place it in our information sheet, let's say column F.

So our sub-categories could be Sub 1 (G1), Sub 2 (E1), Sub 3 (E1) etc. but we need to find that value and have it display in F:F.

Sadly, the FILTER formula doesn't seem to be able to format the values it finds in a single formula, but places them alongside each other.

I am terribly sorry for the wall of text, but I am trying to be as thorough as possible. Feel free to edit as necessary!

Below is an image of what the spreadsheet looks like, to get a better understanding of what I mean. The Sub 1, Sub 2 and Sub 3 are all supposed to be under the Sub-Category Column.

[image: Example Of Current Spreadsheet]

And here is an example of what the Form Responses sheet looks like.

[image]

The reason I used FILTER in the first place was because it can pull ALL information from the form responses sheet at once with a single formula, and I have an exact copy of the cells as shown in the image but for "Incoming" and as such whenever I tried to work with INDEX and MATCH I would be left with empty cells (due to referencing static cells such as B1, B2, E4 etc.).

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Instructions

1. Add an auxiliary column, let say it will be AA
2. Add a formula to AA1 to concatenate the subcategories values. Example

```
=ArrayFormula(G:G&H:H&I:I)
```

3. Use a formula like

```
=FILTER('Form Responses'!$AA:$AA,'Form Responses'!$B:B = "Outgoing")
```

## Explanation

- `ArrayFormula` returns an array of values
- `&` concatenates the values of each column, row by row

Comment: Please post the follow-up questions as a one or several new questions.

Comment: Questions should not be changed in a way that invalidate useful answers. If my answer was completely wrong, you could edit your question to clarify it, but it looks to me that your comments are not to ask for clarification but to extend the answer beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I suggest you to post your follow-up questions as a new post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127126/discussion-between-ruben-and-deadmano).