# Remove Blank Entries Imported By ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

As a follow-up question to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365049/displaying-filter-value-in-single-cell-based-on-existing-cell-value) that sparked this one, I would like to know how I can filter out blank values imported by the ArrayFormula formula.

The formula in Helper!A1 is

```
=ArrayFormula(
'Form Responses'!G:G&'Form Responses'!H:H&'Form Responses'!I:I&'Form Responses'!J:J&
'Form Responses'!K:K&'Form Responses'!L:L&'Form Responses'!M:M&'Form Responses'!N:N&
'Form Responses'!O:O&'Form Responses'!P:P&'Form Responses'!Q:Q&'Form Responses'!R:R&
'Form Responses'!S:S&'Form Responses'!T:T
)
```

The issue is that I will never know where the gap is, as this is user input from a form and is based on the category as well. Here's an example of what a submission MIGHT look like, notice the gaps due to the INCOMING section:

[image]

Regarding the ArrayFormula formula itself, is there any downside to me having created a new "Helper" sheet so as to keep any edits from the actual FORM created sheet? My formula is then:

```
=FILTER(Helper!A:A, Helper!B:B = "Outgoing" )
```

where Helper!B1 contains:

```
=ArrayFormula('Form Responses'!B:B)
```

which contains either the "Outgoing" or "Incoming" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Instructions

Instead of adding on `Helper!B1` the formula `=ArrayFormula('Form Responses'!B:B)` try the following:

```
=FILTER(
{'Form Responses'!$AA:$AA,'Form Responses'!$B:B}, 
LEN('Form Responses'!$AA:$AA), 'Form Responses'!$B:B = "Outgoing"
)
```

You even could remove the formula on `Helper!A1`.

## Explanation

- Filter allow the use of several conditions.
- Filter allows the use of arrays as arguments.
- Google Sheets spreadsheets have a limit on the number of cells and reducing the number of formulas will help on to improve the spreadsheet performance.

## References

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)